# How can I return the array after deleting an element?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, vector, dynamic

The following function

```
int* del_element(int* vector, int dim, int el)
{
    // ...?
}
```

is receiving a dinamically allocated array. What could I write inside of it in order to delete the element and also to return the array obtained?

Comment: Why not use a `std::vector`?

Comment: did you try something? Why did you tag `vector`? Using a `vector` this would be trivial, without it is unnecessarily complicated. Can you use a `vector`?

Comment: only as an exercise you should write such code yourself, but such exercise only makes sense when you aldready know what you are doing. Otherwise just use `std::vector` and its `erase`

Comment: Unrelated note: Allocating and freeing memory is expensive. Normally if you are just deleting elements from an array, you simply move the surviving array elements after the deleted elements back to write over the deleted elements, update a wee bit of book-keeping to track of the count of elements in the allocation and leave the allocation itself alone.

Comment: Andrew.09: You said "_I can't change that function unfortunately_" - but now, you have? You have already gotten answers for your original question, so you shouldn't edit the question so radically that the answers you've gotten don't make sense any more. I've reverted your change of the function's signature.

Answer (score 1):

This is *not* a good idea, but it's answering the question. In the original question you had the note "*to delete its dimension*" which I interpreted as that you want to *shrink* the allocated memory. Example:

```
#include <algorithm> // std::copy_n
#include <iostream>

int* del_element(int* vector, int dim, int el) {
    int* rv = nullptr;
    if(--dim > 0) {            // must have at least 1 element
        rv = new int[dim];     // allocate new memory

        // copy the the elements before `el`:
        std::copy_n(vector, el, rv);
    
        // copy the elements after `el`:
        std::copy_n(vector + el + 1, dim - el, rv + el); 
    }
    delete[] vector; // delete the old data
    return rv;       // return the new data (nullptr if empty)
}

int main() {
    int* v = new int[10]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    
    v = del_element(v, 10, 5); // erase the sixth element

    for(int* it = v, *end = v + 9; it != end; ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << '\n';
    }

    delete[] v;
}
```

Without the need for shrinking the allocated memory, you could just `std::move` the data to erase the selected element:

```
int* del_element(int* vector, int dim, int el) {
    
    // move the elements after `el` one step to "the left":
    std::move(vector + el + 1, vector + dim, vector + el);
    
    return vector;
}
```

A better approach would be to use a `std::vector<int>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    
    v.erase(v.begin() + 5); // erase the sixth element
    
    for(int value : v) {
        std::cout << value << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe answering the question. For all we know `int* v = new int[10]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};` is actually `int v[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};` in the asker's code and the answer is "You can't do this, D00d."

Comment: @user4581301 "_a dinamically allocated array_" suggests that it is in fact dynamically allocated though.

Comment: I'll give you that and hope they didn't `malloc` the sucker.

Comment: @user4581301 The thought occured to me too :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a **bad** idea (or maybe a bad school exercise). Please use a `std::vector` or, in the worst case, a `std::array`.

(Also, maybe do not call a plain array a “`vector`”, do not call `size` a `dim` (which may be confused with the number of dimensions), do not use an `int` were `size_t` should be, avoid raw pointers when possible etc.)

The function should be returning a `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` to clearly document the ownership transfer.

If you are supposed to dispose of the original array, take a `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` argument. If you are **not** supposed to dispose of the original array, take a `const int *` argument.

The most importantly, double-check everything with `valgrind`; it must terminate error-free.

Last but not least, if possible, do not limit your element type to `int`; your future self will thank you.

```cpp
#include <memory>

template<typename Element>
std::unique_ptr<Element[]> del_element(std::unique_ptr<Element[]> array,
                                       size_t size, size_t idx) {
  auto result = std::make_unique<Element[]>(size - 1);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < idx; ++i) result[i] = array[i];
  for (size_t i = idx + 1; i < size; ++i) result[i - 1] = array[i];
  return result;
}
```

Also, set up a printing function for debugging.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename Element>
void print_array(const Element *array, size_t size) {
  std::cout << '[';
  if (size) {
    std::cout << *array;
    for (size_t i = 1; i < size; ++i) std::cout << ", " << array[i];
  }
  std::cout << ']' << std::endl;
}
```

Also, don’t forget to test it. `valgrind` is your friend!

```cpp
int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<int[]> first = std::make_unique<int[]>(7);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 7; ++i) first[i] = i - 3;
  print_array(first.get(), 7);
  std::unique_ptr<int[]> second = del_element(std::move(first), 7, 3);
  print_array(second.get(), 6);
  std::unique_ptr<int[]> third = del_element(std::move(second), 6, 0);
  print_array(third.get(), 5);
  std::unique_ptr<int[]> forth = del_element(std::move(third), 5, 4);
  print_array(forth.get(), 4);
  std::unique_ptr<int[]> fifth = del_element(std::move(forth), 4, 2);
  print_array(fifth.get(), 3);
  std::unique_ptr<int[]> sixth = del_element(std::move(fifth), 3, 1);
  print_array(sixth.get(), 2);
  std::unique_ptr<int[]> seventh = del_element(std::move(sixth), 2, 0);
  print_array(seventh.get(), 1);
  std::unique_ptr<int[]> eighth = del_element(std::move(sixth), 1, 0);
  print_array(eighth.get(), 0);
}
```

Last but not least, please throw all this nonsense away and use a `std::vector`, `std::deque`, `std::list` or whatever fits your use case. It has more features and fewer bugs.

Comment: Yes. This is a school exercise. And I can't change that function unfortunately. That's why it sounds a little weird maybe

Comment: Well, it would be a good C school exercise for sure, but starting a C++ class from raw pointers is (IMHO) a bad idea. The reasons why raw pointers are frowned upon include (but are not limited to) their ignorance of exception safety and zero scoping awareness. By contrast, an object-based “pointer” (e.g. a `std::unique_ptr`) solves these issues.